# Use of undeclared unstable module when module is imported and a cfg attribute is used

Tags: import, module, rust

I have the below code:

```
#[cfg(all(feature = "unstable", unique))]
#[cfg(all(feature = "unstable", heap_api))]
#[cfg(all(feature = "unstable", alloc))]

use std::ptr::Unique;
use std::mem;
use alloc::heap;

pub struct Foo<T> {
    arr: Unique<T>,
    cap: usize,
    probe_limit: usize,
}
```

However, when I try to compile it with `cargo build --features "unstable"` I get a compilation error. Note that I am using the nightly build of Rust and the unstable feature is set up correctly (otherwise I would get a different error).

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `Unique` in this scope
  --> src/hash/arr.rs:27:8
   |
27 |   arr: Unique<T>,
   |        ^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: possible candidate is found in another module, you can import it into scope
   | use std::ptr::Unique;
```

I'm not sure why `Unique` is not found. I am should be using it at the top of my file. `use ::std::ptr::Unique` does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Let's deconstruct your `cfg` instruction:

```
#[cfg(all(feature = "unstable", unique))]
```

This is an `outer` attribute, meaning it is outside the item it will change, and will apply to the next item. With the `cfg` attribute, it means "if the feature inside the parenthesis is enabled, do the next block", and `all` is a AND between the features. So you have something like "if features unstable and unique are enabled, do the next statement.

[Attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/attributes.html)! What you want is to have the `inner` attribute `feature(unique)` conditionally if you have set the feature `unstable` on the command line. A conditional attribute can be obtained with [`cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/conditional-compilation.html#cfg_attr).

```
#![cfg_attr(feature = "unstable", feature(unique))]
```

This can be read as if feature `unstable` is enabled, then enable the inner `feature(unique)`. Then you will be able to use `std::ptr::Unique`.

You should also add a `#[cfg(feature = "unstable")]` before the `use` and your `struct`, so that they won't be usable if the feature is not enabled.

Comment: I believe this is addressing a different issue. My problem seems to be solved when I re-arrange the import order. If I import heap first, then Unique, then mem it works fine.